# Stalk is a local object of a sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $X$. The stalk is the direct limit
$$ \mathcal{F}_x = \lim_{\underset{V \ni x}{\longrightarrow}} \mathcal{F}(V) $$

Let $U \subset X$ be an open subset that contains $x \in X$. Then $$(\mathcal{F}|_U)_x \cong \mathcal{F}_x \ . $$

This seems to be correct as the stalk is local, and due to the direct limit we pass through $U$ and thus consider $\mathcal{F}|_U$ and its restriction.

How to prove it formally?

Comment: Either you can appeal to the theorem that if $\mathscr{C}$ is cofinal in $\mathscr{A}$, then $$\varinjlim_{a\in \mathscr{A}} G_a = \varinjlim_{c\in\mathscr{C}} G_c$$ (well, canonically isomorphic), or you prove that. If you can appeal, it's trivial. If you need to prove, not hard.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's confusing that you use $U$ twice, so I'm replacing your second $U$ with $V$.  You can use the Yoneda lemma: maps out of the limit are the same as maps out of all $F(U)$ with compatibilities.  This is by definition of limit if you like.  The functor I mean here is the functor taking an object $X$ to the set of maps $X \rightarrow F(U)$ for all $U$, with compatibility with restriction.

You want to construct a natural isomorphism between maps out of the all $F(U)$ and maps out of all $F(U')$ such that $U' \subset V$ (with compatibilities).  If you have maps out of all $F(U')$ such that $U' \subset V$, then for general $U$ you can precompose with the restriction maps $F(U) \rightarrow F(U')$ for all $U$.  Check that this is a welld-defined natural transf. in the sense that all restriction maps are compatible (exercise).  Then show that this natural transformation is a natural isomorphism: injectivity is obvious and surjectivity is due to every open $U$ having a sub-open contained in $V$.

The details you should probably convince yourself of, I think the important thing here is that the Yoneda lemma makes the proof a lot cleaner.  (I am using the version where, to show that two objects $X$, $Y$ are isomorphic is the same as showing that the functors $Hom(-, X)$ and $Hom(-, Y)$ are naturally isomorphic.

Comment: I understand that if we set $U \ni x$ as our fixed open subset. I need to construct a map from 
$$ F_x = \lim_{V \ni x} F(V) $$ to $$ (F|_U)_x = \lim_{U \supset W \ni x} F(W) \ . $$ The map would be sending $f \in F(V)$ to $f|_{V \cap U} \in F(V \cap U)$. After checking compatabilities this would induce the isomorphism.

Comment: Maybe, I mean I know what you mean since the fact is "intuitively" "obvious" but the formalism isn't so clear to me -- elements in the limit are not elements in F(U) but some sort of equivalence class.

At any rate, this sort of thing isn't my strong suit haha.  But Yoneda is a really useful thing to internalize which is why I'm suggesting it